# Is there a cost for Azure Site Recovery if you finish one-time migration from on-prem to Azure within 31 days?

Tags: azure, vmware, azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v

["Customers can replicate on-premises workloads to Azure with Azure Site Recovery for 31 days at no charge, effectively making migration to Azure free."](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-site-recovery-ga-move-vmware-aws-hyper-v-and-physical-servers-to-azure/)

While the above statement from a Microsoft blog indicates ASR is free for a one-time migration done within 31 days, I wonder why the word "effectively" was used. I'm looking for a confirmation from those who have used it for a one-time migration that you just have to pay for Storage, storage transactions and outbound data transfer and **there is no per instance cost**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Effectively" here means that there is no cost as long as you do not continue using the service, incur data egress fee charges, etc.  Basically, it's free to use as long as you remember to fail over your VMs, disable ASR and delete your Recovery Services Vault after you have finished your replication.  (It should go without saying that the bandwidth you'll require obviously isn't "free").

Where people get in to trouble is forgetting that ASR is still running and doing something like copying a VHD after it's been migrated.  Once you failover the VMs to Azure for the final time, you start incurring normal IaaS charges.

One final note - if you have really busy workloads or a huge amount of VMs, it's possible to incur some small charges for Storage Transactions with ASR, especially if you're using premium storage.  I've never seen this be more than a few dollars a month.

If you think there's a chance that you might use the service after 31 days, you can use this tool to estimate charges:  http://oms-calculator-webapp.azurewebsites.net/home